# One dimensional array of strings being parsed to 2d by angular resource

Tags: json, angularjs

The following JSON response from the server

```
[
    "hello",
    "world"
]
```

is being parsed into a 2d array by this ngResource service

```
myService.factory('Name', function($resource){
    return $resource(site_url+'api/accounts/:accountId/names/', {}, {
        list: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
    });
});
```

called like so

```
$scope.names = Name.list({accountId:$scope.account.id}, function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

traces to

```
[{"0":"h","1":"e","2":"l","3":"l","4":"o"},{"0":"w","1":"o","2":"r","3":"l","4":"d"}]
```

Any hints?

Comment: For how to transform the response, see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491240/626810

Answer (score 99, accepted):

TLDR; **ngResource** expects an object or an array of ***objects*** in your response.

---

When `isArray` is set to `true` in the list of actions, the **ngResource** module iterates over each item received in the response and it creates a new instance of a Resource. To do this Angular performs a deep copy between the item received and the `Resource` class, which gives us an object with special methods (`$save`, `$delete` and so on)

Check the [source here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js#L385-L394).

Internally angular uses **[angular.copy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)** to perform the deep copy and this function only operates with **objects** and **arrays**, when we pass a string, it will treat it like an object.

Strings in JS can behave as arrays by providing sequential access to each character. `angular.copy` will produce the following when passed a string

```
angular.copy('hi',{})   => {0:'h', 1:'i'}
```

Each character becomes a value in an object, with its index set as the key. **ngResource** will provide a resource with properties `0` and `1`.

---

Your choices are:

#### Use the lower level **$http** service

```
$http.get('/res').success(function(data){
  $scope.test = data;
});
```

#### Return an array of objects in your json response

```
[{'data': "hello"}, {'data': "world"}]
```

#### Intercept the response and change your data

If you cannot modify the data the server sends back and want to use **ngResource** you will need to transform the response. Read how to do it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)

Comment: thanks, i spent 12 hours searching a solution. thanks to you i won't spend 25 hours :). I was returning a single object and isArray was set to false, however i still had the same problem. I fixed it by still using resource and putting it in a list from the server side as you suggested.

Comment: `isArray: false` not working, you need to transform returned string to object  check this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725445/angularjs-resource-not-working-with-an-array-returned-from-a-rest-api/22491240#22491240)

Answer (score -1):

I have been struggling with this as well. Here is my solution by adjusting the service slighly by using query

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Name', function($resource, $sce) {
  var path = "test.json";

  return $resource(path, {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: false
    }
  })
});

app.controller('testController', function($scope, Name) {
  $scope.result;

  $scope.getResult = function() {
    Name.query(function(data) {
      $scope.result = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.getResult();
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

<head>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testController">
  <h1>{{result.surname}}</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

and the JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "Homer",
    "surname":  "Simpson",
    "Town": "Springfield"
}
```

and also working Plunker if interested: http://plnkr.co/edit/SwqlZyqZ4zfcpaLxaf39

Hope this help someone ...