# Angularjs resource query() result array as a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I like the way the `query()` method returns an array of resources, which can be saved to the server again.
I am trying to use Angular against the [Drupal RestWS](http://drupal.org/project/restws) module, which returns an object with several "meta" properties and a property called list where the actual data are stored. Is there please a way of telling the resource to take that array instead ?

Example : `GET author.json` returns :

```
first: "http://dgh/author?page=0"
last: "http://dgh/author?page=0"
list: [{id:1, type:author, uid:{uri:http://dgh/user/1, id:1, resource:user}, created:1367770006,…},…]
self: "http://dgh/author"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the latest Angular version (1.1.2 or later), you can configure the resource with a transformResponse:

```
var MyResource = $resource(
    '/author.js',
    {},
    {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET',
            transformResponse: function (data) {return angular.fromJson(data).list},
            isArray: true //since your list property is an array
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: this looks promising, but i cant get it to work, I keep getting `TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'`. I think its a problem i usually have when an object is returned for a method that has isArray:true. BTW, is the new version documented somewhere ?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll see if I can fix it in a JSFiddle. The docs are here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ngResource.$resource , but the transformResponse isn't that well documented :(

Comment: I've changed the code a bit. This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/59nhp/ (with other data, so it's not the same transform function)

Comment: Set isArray:true, parse the data and return the array: `list:{isArray:true,method:'get',transformResponse: function (data, headers) {return JSON.parse(data).list; }}` - http://plnkr.co/edit/8tj1qqqzZ2KLWkDhT2mQ