# AngularJS displaying data in json Format.Need it in normal form?

Tags: angularjs, json, stringify

How this will work normally?

Hi I have created a simple Rest service:

```
@GET
@Path("/SayHello")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String sayhello(){
      String name="Hello";
      return name;
  }
```

And calling it using $resource from angular's MIME Service and controller like this:

```
service.factory('Tester', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/Resource/rest/SayHello', {}, {
        test: { method: 'GET',isArray: false ,cache : false  },
     })
});
```

And in the controller I am calling a REST service through Tester Service:

```
Tester.test({},function success(response){
        console.log("Tester Success: "+JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.output=response;
    },
    function error(errorResponse){
        console.log("Tester Error: "+JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
    });
```

Now on printing this "output" in template `{{output}}`

It is displaying it in json Format - `{"0":"H","1":"e","2":"l","3":"l","4":"o"}` rather than 'Hello'.

Using `$http` it working, but not using `$resource`. I there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably not angulars fault, the problem is with the server. check your server settings like content-type or encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876593/resource-query-return-split-strings-array-of-char-instead-of-a-string) question. I made quick proof of concept and I got same issue. Simply you can wrap your message into something like that

```
{
  "message": "Hello"
}
```