# It is possible to display geojson as table in ng-repeat loop in Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, leaflet, geojson

So I have already created table with searching filters and pagination.
Now I would like to make it interact with map as well.
Problem is I am trying to access geojson in wrong way, so maybe somebody can help.

My geojson:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },

    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Berlin",
                "country": "Germany"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [28.410585, -11.293361]
            }
        }, .......

    ]
}
```

The service that retrieves it:

```
var AppMapDirectory = angular.module('DirectoryAppMap', ['ngResource']);

AppMapDirectory.factory("Directory", function($resource) {
   return $resource("/result.json", {}, {
       get: {
           method: "GET",
           cache: true
       }
   });
});
```

The controller that puts it in the scope:

```
AppMapDirectory.controller("DirectoryMapList", function($scope, Directory, $filter) {
   Directory.query(function(data) {
      $scope.list = data.features;

   });
```

And the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="hf in list">
<td>{{ hf.properties.name }}</td>
<td>{{ hf.properties.category }}</td>

</tr>
```

or

```
<tr ng-repeat="feature in list">
<td>{{ feature.properties.name }}</td>
<td>{{ feature.properties.category }}</td>

</tr>
```

I saw on stackoverflow that somebody was typing something like this:

```
$scope.list = data.features[];
```

but in my case json is not loading at all then

Mayby sb will say that i should use json instead of geojson, but my main point is to make map and table interactive so both will change if searching will work.

Or it is possible to use json data and geojson from the same source?

I plan to use leaflet directive with angular, it seems easy to use just geojson for map, but how to use geojson for table? Is it possible?

Comment: The idea of a snippet is to create one complete working example. To simply display pieces of code, indent them with four spaces instead.

Comment: thanks for making my code readable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, geojson is just another case of json and it'll work fine.

There's directives like the [leaflet directive](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/) that do all the hard work for you and allow you to easily display geojson on a map.

See https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/examples/geojson-example.html for an example. You don't even need the ng-repeat.

I see something odd in your Directory service. You define the `get` method in the service, but call the `query` method in the controller. The `query` method, by default, expects to return an array and will throw an exception when it runs into your geojson data which is an object.

When I replace

```
Directory.query(function(data)
```

with

```
Directory.get(function(data)
```

the table gets filled properly.

Comment: i found this leaflet directive and geojson works already but just on map, i cannot display geojson in table.

Comment: i though about something similar to this http://www.zevross.com/web_development/worldcup/  , when searching is done table and map are changing dynamically.

Comment: i read somewhere how to add data by directory service and actually it works with query and plain json data, but it is obvious to me now that it is odd to define one thing and call other. Huge thanks ;)

Comment: both query and get can work, but the structure defined in result.json is an object, not an array. $resource gets upset when it receives an object in query, you'd have to configure it saying `query: {isArray: false}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725445/angularjs-resource-not-working-with-an-array-returned-from-a-rest-api