# Firebase request: Error in resource configuration for action `array`. Expected response to contain an object but got an GET

Tags: arrays, firebase

I found lots of posts on this issue and tried to implement some of the solutions proposed [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725445/angularjs-resource-not-working-with-an-array-returned-from-a-rest-api)

But it still does not work and I am wondering if using firebase could be an issue. I have created a service linking to my Firebase datasource:

```
 servicesModule.factory("postsDB", function($resource){
    return $resource("https://<datasource>.firebaseio.com/Posts/:id", {
        id: "@id"
     },
     {
         update: {
             method: "PUT",
             isArray : true
         }
    });
});
```

Then my controller:

```
controllersModule.controller('BlogCtrl', ["$scope", "postsDB", function($scope, postsDB) {

        postsDB.query(function(posts){
             $scope.myPosts = posts;
         })
}]);
```

The ng-repeat result:

```
<div class="col s12 m6"  id="postItems" ng-repeat="post in myPosts">
<h3>{{post.Title}}</h3>
{{post.Body}}
{{post.Author}}
</div>
```

I really do not understand what:

*Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter*

means (as usual with angular errors) except that it is obviously expecting an array and I though that the whole point of using `postsDB.query` was to do just that. I have added isArray: true above but it has no effect whatsoever. Why aren't my posts being loaded if the resource exists as a JSON posts array?

Comment: You added `isArray` to `update`, not to `query`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20043070/2163901). Why not use AngularFire or Firebase's libraries?Also, I believe you need to append `.json` to use their REST API.

Comment: Hey thanks Anid, you should add your comments as answers so I can accept them. Both adding isArray to query and appending json to the datasource seem to have worked. I am not familiar with Firebase/Angularfire enough yet to know how to implement libraries but will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things: you need to append `.json` to the path to use Firebase's REST API and second, you'll need to set `isArray: false` specifically for the query method.

```
servicesModule.factory("postsDB", function($resource) {
    return $resource("https://<datasource>.firebaseio.com/Posts/:id.json", {
                id: "@id"
            },
            {
                update: {
                    method: "PUT",
                    isArray: true
                },
                query: {
                    method: "GET",
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
});
```