# Invalid result from ngResource request with string array

Tags: json, angularjs

i've the following ngResource defined:

```
angular.module('LicenseServices', ['ngResource']).
    factory('License', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/licenses/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            //...
            'getLicenseTypes': { method: 'GET', url: 'api/licenses/types', isArray: true }
        });
    });
```

The result of the GET request is:

```
["Trial","Standard"]
```

But using the resource in a controller:

```
$scope.licenseTypes = License.getLicenseTypes()
```

i get the following result:

```
licenseTypes: 
[ undefined, { 
0: S
1: t
2: a
3: n
4: d
5: a
6: r
7: d
 } ]
```

I'm using AngularJS 1.1.4 with Chrome.

Whats wrong with my resource definition?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813673/one-dimensional-array-of-strings-being-parsed-to-2d-by-angular-resource?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really not much point in using `$resource` for data structures like those. The thing is that `$resource` works great for RESTful endpoint where all the HTTP verbs are used. To make this easy AngualarJS extends incoming objects with convenience methods ($save, $delete etc.). If you return primitives there is no room for extension and one of the major benefits of `$resource` is gone.

In short: if you are just after fetching data $resource is an overkill IMO, stick with the `$http` instead.