# infinite loop when trying to retrieve data from controller in view using angular $resource.Query() method

Tags: sails.js

I'm building a small sails.js + angular.js app.

Here is a fiddle that roughly shows what my code looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/WEk3F/

```
index: function(req, res, next) {

  Food.find({}, function foundFoods(err, foods) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    var data = {
      name1: "test1",
      name2: "test2"
    }
    res.view(
      'food/index', {
        foods: data
    });
  });
},

    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="FoodController">
            <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="food in foods">
                    {{food.name}}
               </li>
            </ul>
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input name="name" ng-model="editableFood.name" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My problem is, that whenever i try to retrieve the data from my controller, i don't get those 2 items but instead it renders more and more items and just doesn't stop. even the page gets slow and unresponsive and almost freezes.

When i say

```
$scope.foods = [{"name": "test1"},{"name": "test2"}];
```

instead of

```
$scope.foods = Food.query();
```

it works. but i want the data to be coming from the backend via the controller.
the other methods (add, update etc) of the angular.js $resource module work fine for me.

/food maps to the index action of my FoodController and just returns some fixed test data

Comment: Are you sure your API is returning an array of objects?

Comment: thx Sam, you made me think of the problem in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out what the problem was.

the angular.js $resource should only be used in a restful way, so the GET request to my food/index should return an array of objects.

in my case this wasn't the case. instead i used the index action of my controller to render a view and the result was therefor html.

so my options are to define a new route, that the $resource takes for the Query() command or define a new action that i use for the view/html stuff and use the index action again for pure restful response.

thx @sam hunter for pointing me to the right direction

the infinite loop that i received is explained here: [One dimensional array of strings being parsed to 2d by angular resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813673/one-dimensional-array-of-strings-being-parsed-to-2d-by-angular-resource?rq=1)

i love stack overflow

Comment: You're very welcome. I couldn't be sure from the code you provided, but that was my guess ;) I got sick of ngResource giving me problems, so I switched to [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)