# angularjs resource query misinterprets array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, resources

My REST server is returning the following from `/blog`:

```
["hello","yo"]
```

This is my entire angularjs app:

```
var myapp = new angular.module("myapp", ["ngResource"]);

myapp.controller("MainCtl", ["$scope", "$resource", function($scope, $resource){
    var Blog = $resource("/blog/:entry", {entry: '@entry'});
    $scope.entries = Blog.query();
}]);
```

When I put `{{entries}}` somewhere in the html, I see this: `[{"0":"h","1":"e","2":"l","3":"l","4":"o"},{"0":"y","1":"o"}]`

Somehow angular is misinterpreting this array of values. I also tried this with exactly the same results:

```
myapp.controller("MainCtl", ["$scope", "$resource", function($scope, $resource){
    var Blog = $resource("/blog/:entry", {entry: '@entry'}, {
        list: {
            url: "/blog",
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
                var h = ["hello","yo"];
                console.log(h);
                return h;
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.entries = Blog.list();
}]);
```

Interestingly, that `console.log` call prints the correct value.

Comment: This is angular 1.2.10 by the way.

Comment: This is most likely how you're sending the response from your server side. What are you using there?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kZJkRp0C for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a duplicate of [One dimensional array of strings being parsed to 2d by angular resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813673/one-dimensional-array-of-strings-being-parsed-to-2d-by-angular-resource)

When using $resource, if isArray = false, the expected response is a JSON object:

```
{
   "foo" : "bar"
}
```

If isArray = true, the expected response is supposed to be a JSON array *of objects*:

```
[
    { "foo" : "bar" },
    { "faa" : "bah" }
]
```

You have three options in this situation:

1. Use $http instead of $resource
2. Use $http's `transformResponse` functionality (see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)
3. If you have control over the API, you can change the structure the response you are sending. Depending on semantics, you could send an array of objects (use `isArray=true`), or an object containing an array (use `isArray=false`). Whichever makes more sense to you.